# How can I access all imageviews from a position of an adapter of recyclerview in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

In my program, there is a recyclerview. There is an imageview for an each item of the recyclerview. I need to change all item's imageview's image when a condition satisfies. so I need to access whole position's imageview from some position of the adapter. I need to access from inside of the adapter. I searched and found an answer from here. but that I only can access from our fragment/activity page. not from adapter. that code is

`val row: View? = rvLocations?.layoutManager?.findViewByPosition(position)`

How can I access the all views inside the adapter? Thank you

Comment: Please add the adapter class in the question.

Comment: Your question is not clear what exactly you want to say. 
But I think you can access all the views of your item in adapter and can use listeners to do your logic in fragment or activity.
Add your adapter code.

Comment: @TariqHussain I don't want to use it in activity/fragment. I only needs to write code in adapter class. But when we write something in adapter bindview, it only affected to the purticular position. But I want to change the all itemview's imageview.

Comment: ```val row: View? = rvLocations?.layoutManager?.findViewByPosition(position)``` when I use this code. Then I can access it from my activity/fragment. But I have to access from adapter. Can we get layoutmanager from adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depend on how you build your adapter , here is complete adapter boilerplate using `viewBinding` in `kotlin`

```
class ItemListAdapter(
    private val list: List<ItemDataModel>,
    private val listener: OnItemClickListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemListAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    interface OnItemClickListener{
        fun onItemClick(view: View, position: Int)
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(private var binding: ItemListRcvBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(item: ItemDataModel, position: Int) {
            // you can get access to all your view and its position here
            // e.g:

            // context
            val context = binding.imageView1.context

            // clicklistener
            binding.imageView1.setOnclickListener{ view ->
               listener.onItemClick(view, position)
             }
         
            // change image by condition
            when(item.condision){
               conditionA -> binding.imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1)
               else -> //do something
            }

            //or
            
            when(position){
               0 -> binding.imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1)
               else -> //do something
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = ItemListRcvBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context))
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(item,position)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = list.size
    
}
```

in activity/fragment

```kotlin
...
adapter = ItemListAdapter(myList1, object:  ItemListAdapter.OnItemClickListener{
        override fun onItemClick(view: View, position: Int){
         //do something
     }
   }

...
```